# Navigation Bar, Title and Buttons are hidden in View Controller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar

I have a problem with navigation bar not getting displayed in iOS 8 (Xcode beta 3). The View Controller is connected to a TableView Controller (embedded in a navigation controller) via Segue (Show/Push). As a result of this connection the View Controller shows a navigation bar.

[image: Screenshot showing both the bars.]

Now when I to place a custom navigation bar with controls over the inferred navigation bar, it gets hidden. What could be the problem? I do not want to hide the navigation bar via code.Is there any way I can specify Send to Front option for my custom navigation bar?

[image: Screenshot after placing custom navigation bar over the inferred one]

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue by adding navigation item instead of custom navigation bar. Then added the button bar items to the navigation item. Now the title and the controls are getting displayed.
[image]

Comment: Exactly, even you can set title as-
self.title = "Task Detail"